# Inappbrowser usando Phonegap build

Tags: jquery

tenho uma aplicação que roda no mobile compilado no PG build Cli 5.2.0
nesse app tenho alguns links externos pra abrir. implementei o inappbrowser para poder fechar o navegador aberto e retornar para o app. no entanto são varios links diferentes. Tem alguma forma onde eu posso fazer uma função sem o link especifico e so especificar no botão quando eu for fazer a chamada da função? pra q eu não tenha que fazer uma função pra cada link diferente.
Ex: que estou usando.

```
<head>
    <!-- o script esta rodando no cabeçalho -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function face() {
         var ref = window.open('http://facebook.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
    }

    </script>

<body>
```

o botão fica no corpo do app e precisa ter varios botões desse com links diferentes...

```
   <li><button onclick="face()">Pagina do face</button></li>
```

Comment: Podes colocar o link aqui `onclick="face(link...)"` e depois fazer dentro da função `... ction face(link) {window.open(link, ...` será isso que queres? Repara que o teu `</head>` está em falta.

Comment: Vlws irmão acredito que isso vai resolver meu problema, depois do link saiu com ... ali no windows open, o que vai depois?

Comment: Sergio pode ajudar onde eu estou errando?...

<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function face(link) {
         var ref = window.open('link', '_blank', 'location=yes');
    }

    </script>
</head> 



No corpo...

<button onclick="face('https://facebook.com')">Ofertastes</button>

Comment: Obrigado irmao deu certo achei o erro... estava usando 'link' dentro de windows.open... e nao precisa de '   '

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar a mesma função mas passares-lhe como argumento o link que queres abrir.

Assim no HTML podes ter:

```
<li><button onclick="face('http://um.link.com')">Pagina do Um</button></li>
<li><button onclick="face('http://outro.link.com')">Pagina do Outro</button></li>
```

e a função ficaria assim:

```
function face(meuLink) { 
    window.open(meuLink, '_blank', 'location=yes'); 
}
```

Eu chamei `meuLink` à variável, mas podes dar o nome que quiseres.